# Unable to get id from url in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with reactjs and right now i want to get id from url, For example my current url is

```
"http://localhost:3000/user/19"
```

so how can i get id from url in reactjs,Here is my current code

```
const User = (props) => {
    const params = useParams();
    const [users, setUsers] = useState({});
    let { id } = useParams();
    console.log(params);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("aara h");
        async function fetchData() {
            const res = await axios(
                `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments/${id}`
            );
            console.log("INDI", res.data);
            setUsers(res.data);
        }
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    return (
        <div style={{ width: "80%", margin: "0 auto" }}>
            <div
                style={{
                    margin: "20px",
                    marginRight: "auto",
                    borderRadius: "20px",
                    border: "2px solid #000",
                    width: "50%",
                    padding: "10px",
                }}
            >
    );
```

Here is my routes file

```
export default function Router() {
  return useRoutes([
    {
      path: "/",
      element: <Layout />,
      errorElement: <Page404 />,
      children: [
        { element: <HomePage />, index: true },
        { element: <User />, path:`user/:id` },
      ],
    },
  ]);
}
```

Comment: Does your code not work? I wouldn't have `useParams()` twice like that but what does your `console.log(params)` show?

Comment: FYI `id` should be in your effect hook's dependencies

Comment: @Phil "console.log" showing "[object object] "

Comment: You sure about that? Can't see that being possible with the code in your question

Comment: @Phil yes i am sure i am not getting anyting in console , only showing "object object"

Comment: @Phil even i tried with "params.id" also but still not working for me

Comment: Have you added params in useEffect dependency ?

Comment: means ? i already post my code

Comment: Works fine here ~ https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-roman-elvsg7?file=/src/User.jsx. This is not reproducible

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't able to completely replicate your code as I would be missing a few elements, however, I was able to get something close enough to take a look at your issue. I believe the issue is your path should be `/user/:id` instead of just `user/:id`. You can take a look at what I did here:

[image: Edit React Router Dom w/ Params]

Once again, not a complete 1:1 of your project obviously but what I did here worked without issues. Take a look and let me know if it solves your issue or if you have any other questions.

**Edit** I also tried without leading `/` and it still seemed to work so it'd be hard to tell what your issue with the code provided.

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem (and [neither could I](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-roman-elvsg7?file=/src/User.jsx)), then it's best to _vote-to-close_